# Monaca でのファイルの保存先

Tags: ios, monaca

Monaca で iPad のアプリを作成しています。ファイルをダウンロードするアプリを作成中です。

下記のコードを実機のデバッガで実行すると

```
ファイルを/path/to/downlardsに保存しました。
```

とでますが、実際にはどこに保存されているのでしょうか？

また、保存先のファイルを読み込むには？ （このアプリはデバッガで動作するのでしょうか？）

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
      var directoryEntry;

  document.addEventListener('deviceready', init, false);
  function init() {
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, getFilesFromDirectory, fail);
  // window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, getFilesFromDirectory, fail);
  document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', downloadFile, false);
  }

  function getFilesFromDirectory(fileSystem) {
  directoryEntry = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/downloads/';
  var directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();
  directoryReader.readEntries(putFileName, fail);
  }

  function putFileName(entries) {
      alert(entries.length);
  for ( index = 0; index < entries.length; index++ ) {
      alert(entries[index].fullPath);
  if ( entries[index].isFile ) {
  var listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.textContent = entries[index].name;
  listItem.title = entries[index].fullPath;
  listItem.addEventListener('click', uploadFile, false);
  document.getElementById('fileList').appendChild(listItem);
  }
  }
  }

  function downloadFile() {
  // FileTransferオブジェクトを作成
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

  // ダウンロード先のURIをencodeURIでエンコード

  var uri = encodeURI('http://image.gihyo.co.jp/assets/templates/gihyojp2007/image/gihyojp_logo.png');
  alert(uri);
  // 保存するファイルの名前
  var fileName = 'gihyojp_logo.png';

  // 保存先をフルパスで指定

  var path = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/downloads/';
  alert(path);
  // ファイルのダウンロードを実行
  fileTransfer.download(uri, path, downloadSuccess, downloadFail);
  }

  function downloadSuccess(fileEntry) {
  alert('ファイルを' + fileEntry.fullPath + 'に保存しました。');
  location.reload();
  }

  function downloadFail(fileTransferError) {
  var error = '';

  switch(fileTransferError.code) {
  case FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR:
  error = '第2引数にファイルURLが指定されていません';
  break;
  case FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR:
  error = '不正なファイルパスが第2引数で指定されています';
  break;
  case FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR:
  error = '接続エラー';
  break;
  default: 
  error = '未定義のエラー';
  break;
  }

  alert(error + '\nhttp_status: ' + fileTransferError.http_status);
  }

  function uploadFile(event) {
  // FileTransferオブジェクトを作成
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

  // アップロード先URIをencodeURIでエンコード
  var uri = encodeURI('http://(ホスト名)/receive.php');

  // FileUploadOptionsオブジェクトを作成し，送信時の情報を指定
  var uploadOptions = new FileUploadOptions();
  uploadOptions.fileKey = 'file';
  uploadOptions.fileName = event.target.textContent;

  // ファイルのアップロードを実行
 fileTransfer.upload(event.target.title, uri, uploadSuccess, uploadFail, uploadOptions);
 }

 function uploadSuccess(uploadResult) {
 var result;

 // アップロード先(receive.php)から返るJSONをパース
 if ( 'Android' === device.platform ) {
 result = JSON.parse(uploadResult.response);
 } else { 
 // iOSの場合はエンコードされた文字列になるため，decodeURIでデコード
 result = JSON.parse(decodeURI(uploadResult.response));
 }

 if ( 0 === result.errorCode ) {
 alert('ファイルのアップロードに成功しました\nbytesSent: ' + uploadResult.bytesSent + '\nresponseCode: ' + uploadResult.responseCode);
 } else {
 alert('ファイルのアップロードに失敗しました\n' + result.message + '\nbytesSent: ' + uploadResult.bytesSent + '\nresponseCode: ' + uploadResult.responseCode);
 }
 }

 function uploadFail(fileTransferError) {
 var error = '';

 switch(fileTransferError.code) {
 case FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR:
 error = '第1引数に指定したファイルが見つかりません';
 break;
 case FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR:
 error = '不正なURIが第2引数で指定されています';
 break;
 case FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR:
 error = '接続エラー';
 break;
 default: 
 error = '未定義のエラー';
 break;
 }

 alert(error + '\nhttp_status: ' + fileTransferError.http_status);
 }

 function fail(error) {
 alert('エラーが発生しました。エラーコード: ' + error.code);
 }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>File API Test</h1>
        <p>
        <input id="download" type="button" value="download gihyo logo">
        </p>
        <ul id="fileList"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

ファイルの保存先について回答します。

`cdvfile://localhost/persistent` はアプリ固有のデータフォルダを指すみたいです。

[Monaca Docs::ファイルプラグイン](http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/file/)
↑の「iOS のファイルの永続的な保存場所 ( Persistent Storage )」参照。

`config.ios.xml` に以下の定義を追加していない場合は、`{アプリ固有フォルダ}/Documents` だと思います。

```
// config.ios.xml
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
```

i-FunBoxをインストールしておくと、アプリ固有フォルダへのアクセスが楽ちんですよ。